# ContextMenuStrip assign dynammically to dropdownbutton items C# WINFORM

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, contextmenu, strip

I am building a web browser in WINFORMS. I have a `dropdown` button in a toolstrip. The items of `dropdown` are added dynamically from a XML file at runtime. The dropdown button is used for viewing bookmars. I have a `contextmenu` with add and delete bookmark options. I see no `contextmenuproperty` for `dropdownbutton items.` I need to display the contextmenu on right click for each item in the drop-down button. I couldn't even find `mouseclick` event for items. Therefore no `e.location`

```
//I have got these events do far (just handles the click)
    private void bookmarksDropDownButton2_DropDownItemClicked(object sender, ToolStripItemClickedEventArgs e)
            {
                tabControlBrowser.SelectedTab = tabControlBrowser.TabPages[tabControlBrowser.TabPages.Count - 1];
                getCurrentWebBrowser().Navigate(dictionary[e.ClickedItem.Text]);
                AddressComboBox1.Text = dictionary[e.ClickedItem.Text];
            }
```

I hooked up the events in this way in my code

```
    foreach (ToolStripItem item in bookmarksDropDownButton2.DropDownItems)
            {
                item.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(item_MouseDown);
            }
    private void item_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
              BOOKcontextMenuStrip1.Show(e.Location);
              //this one pop's out the menu at the uppermost corner of the window.
        }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can unfortunately not hook up a `ContextMenu` to individual items in a `ToolStrip`. What you need to do is to set the context menu when you are right-clicking the DropDownButton, on its `MouseDown` event (check for which mouse-button) to the toolstrip itself.

- Or in this case:

You will need instead to dynamically add a handler for the `MouseDown` event for each of your items so you can get the actual item selected (hovered). When an item is right-clicked you assign the context-menu to the tool-strip itself (you can now store the ID of the item clicked in f.ex. the context menu's Tag property).

On the ContextMenu's `Closed` event you then remove the menu from toolstrip (`.ContextMenuStrip=null`).

I'm sorry I don't have a C# example right now. Let me know if it's clear enough or not, in which case I'll try to add an example.

Comment: I already tried this way but the context-menu show's up at the uppermost corner of the scree. Also if I pass the Cursor.X and Cursor.Y as parameters than the drop-down closes and the context-menu prompts up

Comment: That's weird as the context menu by default pops up a where the mouse-button was clicked. I'm using this technique myself and I don't experience this problem. Are you setting any variables on the contextmenu? (there is no need setting any position on the cm).